# Optimizing database query with up to 10mil rows as result

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, solr, large-data

I have a MySQL Query that i need to optimize as much as possible (should have a load time below 5s, if possible)

Query is as follow:

```
SELECT domain_id, COUNT(keyword_id) as total_count
FROM tableName
WHERE keyword_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT keyword_id FROM tableName WHERE domain_id = X)
GROUP BY domain_id
ORDER BY total_count DESC
LIMIT ...
```

- X is an integer that comes from an input
- domain_id and keyword_id are indexed
- database is on localhost, so the network speed should be max

The subquery from the WHERE clause can get up to 10 mil results. Also, for MySQL seems really hard to calculate the COUNT and ORDER BY this count.

I tried to mix this query with SOLR, but no results, getting such a high number of rows at once gives hard time for both MySQL and SOLR

I'm looking for a solution to have the same results, no matter if i have to use a different technology or an improvement to this MySQL query.

Thanks!

---

Query logic is this:

We have a domain and we are searching for all the keywords that are being used on that domain (this is the sub query). Then we take all the domains that use at least one of the keywords found on the first query, grouped by domain, with the number of keywords used for each domain, and we have to display it ordered DESC by the number of keywords used.

I hope this make sense

Comment: why you need inner query you can use domain_id=x in where clause? and add index on domain_id if not present

Comment: @shola please look at the query carefully, it's about related data

Comment: Can you post the EXPLAIN?

Comment: "The subquery from the WHERE clause can get up to 10 mil results." - You have 10 mil distinct keywords ?!?

Comment: @Vatev there are much more but this is not the point...

Comment: it is not clear from your query if the 'tableName' refers to the same table or you have two tables?

Comment: @newtover is the same table

Comment: Unless you post the EXPLAIN, you will get hypothetical responses.

Answer (score 1):

You may try JOIN instead of subquery:

```
SELECT tableName.domain_id, COUNT(tableName.keyword_id) AS total_count
FROM tableName
INNER JOIN tableName AS rejoin
ON rejoin.keyword_id = tableName.keyword_id
WHERE rejoin.domain_id = X
GROUP BY tableName.domain_id
ORDER BY tableName.total_count DESC
LIMIT ...
```

Comment: @GabrielCol can you post EXPLAIN output for both (original and my) queries?

Comment: executing the query applying your approach took 187.6582 sec to execute, which is pretty similar with my original query.

Comment: @GabrielCol just wanted to compare how indexes are used in both queries

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but can you try this please

```
SELECT t1.domain_id, COUNT(t1.keyword_id) as total_count
FROM tableName AS t1 LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT keyword_id FROM tableName WHERE domain_id = X) AS t2
ON t1.keyword_id = t2.keyword_id
WHERE t2.keyword_id IS NTO NULL
GROUP BY t1.domain_id
ORDER BY total_count DESC
LIMIT ...
```

The goal is to replace the `WHERE IN` clause with `INNER JOIN` and that will make it lot quicker. `WHERE IN` clause always make the Mysql server to struggle, but it is even more noticeable when you do it with huge amount of data. Use `WHERE IN` only if it make you query look easier to be read/understood, you have a small data set or it is not possible in another way (but you probably will have another way to do it anyway :) )

Answer (score 0):

In terms of MySQL all you can do is to minimize Disk IO for the query using covering indexes and rewrite it a little more efficient so that the query would benefit from them.

Since `keyword_id` has a match in another copy of the table, `COUNT(keyword_id)` becomes `COUNT(*)`.

The kind of subqueries you use is known to be the worst case for MySQL (it executes the subquery for each row), but I am not sure if it should be replaced with a `JOIN` here, because It might be a proper strategy for your data.

As you probably understand, the query like:

```
SELECT domain_id, COUNT(*) as total_count
FROM tableName
WHERE keyword_id IN (X,Y,Z)
GROUP BY domain_id
ORDER BY total_count DESC
```

would have the best performance with a covering composite index `(keyword_id, domain_id [,...])`, so it is a must. From the other side, the query like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT keyword_id FROM tableName WHERE domain_id = X
```

will have the best performance on a covering composite index `(domain_id, keyword_id [,...])`. So you need both of them.

Hopefully, but I am not sure, when you have the latter index, MySQL can understand that you do not need to select all those `keyword_id` in the subquery, but you just need to check if there is an entry in the index, and I am sure that it is better expressed if you do not use DISTINCT.

So, I would try to add those two indexes and rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT domain_id, COUNT(*) as total_count
FROM tableName
WHERE keyword_id IN (SELECT keyword_id FROM tableName WHERE domain_id = X)
GROUP BY domain_id
ORDER BY total_count DESC
```

Another option is to rewrite the query as follows:

```
SELECT domain_id, COUNT(*) as total_count
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT keyword_id
  FROM tableName
  WHERE domain_id = X
) as kw
JOIN tableName USING (keyword_id)
GROUP BY domain_id
ORDER BY total_count DESC
```

Once again you need those two composite indexes.

Which one of the queries is quicker depends on the statistics in your `tableName`.